# How to calculate the contour integration with branch point?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, mathematics, greens-functions

The question come from a Mutusbara Sum like this
$${ \sum _{ { z=i\omega  }_{ n } } { \frac { -\alpha E\pi  }{ 4{ z }^{ 3 }\sqrt { -\alpha -z }  }  } }$$
it equal a contour integral around Imaginary axis with pole($\omega_n=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{\beta}$,Fermion)
$${ { \frac { 1 }{ 2\pi i } \oint { \frac { -\beta  }{ { e }^{ \beta z }+1 } \quad \frac { -\alpha E\pi  }{ 4{ z }^{ 3 }\sqrt { -\alpha -z }  }  }  } }-{ Res[\frac { -\beta  }{ { e }^{ \beta z }+1 } \quad \frac { -\alpha E\pi  }{ 4{ z }^{ 3 }\sqrt { -\alpha -z }  } ] }_{ z=0 }$$
**the 1st integral have Branch point at $-\alpha$($\alpha \in Reals$)**,when I inflate original imaginary path to Infinite diameter, only the path around the pole $z=-\alpha$ and two parallel(but opposite direction) paths survive. Further more, **I reverse the direction of these paths, and the 1st  integral convert to** 
$$-{ { \frac { 1 }{ 2\pi i } \oint { \frac { -\beta  }{ { e }^{ \beta z }+1 } \quad \frac { -\alpha E\pi  }{ 4{ z }^{ 3 }\sqrt { -\alpha -z }  }  }  } }$$
on a path around the branch point $z=-\alpha$.
**My question is How to calsulate this contour integral? If any one give some help or hint, I would appreciate!!**